# XL Sheet Password Protection using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C# asp.net Web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

XL Sheet Password Protection using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C# asp.net Web form.
Actually I am providing password protection to my XL Sheet but first xl sheet is opening automatic and showing all data of xl sheet but It should not open first time and after download password protection working fine all other functionality working fine.

Below is my full code:

```
private static DataSet GetDataSet()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("Table");

    dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Address", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Phone", Type.GetType("System.String"));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Balaji Selvarajan";
    dr["Address"] = "Reddiyur";
    dr["Phone"] = "000-000-0000";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Balaji S";
    dr["Address"] = "Kattumannar Koil";
    dr["Phone"] = "000-000-0000";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;
}


private static void DataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, Boolean generateIdentity)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlApp.Visible = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables.Count; k++)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = ds.Tables[k];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value,
                        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        ws.Name = dt.TableName;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    ws.Cells[1, j + 1] = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;

                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = (j == 0 && generateIdentity) ?
                                         (i + 1).ToString() : dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
            }
        }
        ws.Protect("1", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true);
    }
    wb.Protect("my", true, true);
    wb.Password = "Test";
    wb.Close();

   // xlApp.Visible = true;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSetToExcel(GetDataSet(), false);
}
```

Comment: Don't do excel interop on a server. It buggy as hell, a security hole big enough to steer a VLCC through and slow as molasse.
Use something reasonable like eeplus.

Comment: Can you update your answer. @ChristianSauer

Comment: Using the above code we kind do any think?. @ChristianSauer

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what's not working instead of full code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do excel interop on a server. It's buggy as hell, it has a security hole big enough to steer a VLCC through and it's slow as molasses. Use something reasonable like epplus, if the license is not a problem. Otherwise, reasonable commercial solutions exist.

Comment: What is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992163/prevent-excel-from-opening-while-creating-excel-file-using-interop .@Christian Sauer

Comment: For docu see the package: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

Comment: Again i have to do RND, already this link is telling working fine na. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992163/prevent-excel-from-opening-while-creating-excel-file-using-interop . @Christian Sauer

Comment: @mazhar Try to understand why that's a bad option (it "works", but it will eat your dev time and create a shitty experience for your customers).

Comment: I have client deadline please I have to close within one hour, i will try your example later please tell me if that above question how to closed xl sheet first time, it will very help to me and later i will convert your example. @Christian Sauer

Comment: @mazhar124 You will have to learn to push pack against unreasonable requests.

Comment: Can you provide your full answer using epplus with code. @Christian Sauer

Comment: Agreed with Christian!